# How to simulate two parallel requests in django testing framework

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application (using uWSGI and nginx, and atomic views) with a view that creates new items of a model in the DB (postgres). Before creating anything the view checks if the record doesn't already exist in the DB, something like:

```
...
try:
    newfile = DataFile.objects.get(md5=request.POST['md5'])
except DataFile.DoesNotExist:
    newfile = DataFile.objects.create(md5=request.POST['md5'], filename=request.POST['filename'])

return JsonResponse({'file_id': newfile.pk})
```

I noticed sometimes this doesn't work, and I get duplicates in the DB (which is easily solved with a unique constraint). I'm not sure why this happens, if there is caching or race conditions, but I'd like to at least cover the behaviour with a test in the Django test framework.However, I do not know how to simulate two parallel requests. Is there a way to fire the next request while not waiting for the first, built into the framework, or should one use multiprocessing or similar for this?

Comment: Have you considered using an atomic operation like [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)?

Comment: @KlausD. I guess this code is kind of old, but I think you're right in that using that would (combined with the unique constraint) solve the issue if I understand the docs correctly. Because only using a constraint and the try/except block would necessitate try/excepting the `.create` line for `IntegrityError` and add another `.get` call?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an async loop to trigger 2 quite simultaneous request.

Example:

```
async def test_case(request):
    try:
        newfile = DataFile.objects.get(md5=request.POST['md5'])
    except DataFile.DoesNotExist:
        newfile = DataFile.objects.create(md5=request.POST['md5'], filename=request.POST['filename'])

    return JsonResponse({'file_id': newfile.pk})


async def simult(request):
    t_case_0 = await test_case(request)
    t_case_1 = await test_case(request)

asyncio.run(simult(request))
```